# by applying the gaussianblur in opencv, why need to increase threadhold parameter?

Tags: opencv

[image]

The above image is a example of detecting a maze, in which I found a problem there is a big difference between using GaussianBlur, threshold together and using threadhold only.
For example,

```
cvtColor(img,img,CV_RGB2GRAY);
threshold(img,img,10,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
```

it works as the original image.
But if apply gaussianblur before threshold with threshold parameter setting to 10, the whole resulted image is white.

```
cvtColor(img,img,CV_RGB2GRAY);
GaussianBlur(img,img,Size(3,3),0);
threshold(img,img,10,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
```

It only works until I increase the threshold parameter to 100,

```
GaussianBlur(img,img,Size(3,3),0);
threshold(img,img,100,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
```

Why there is a huge difference only because of the GaussianBlur, can you help me explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to start off with some common hints first; as they would have fixed your problem right away.

- Display your "in-between" results. This helps to see what is going on
- Read the documentation & tutorials of the functions that you are using

That being said; what is happening is completely expected behaviour. Blurring (eg; the gaussian filter) the image decreases the values of the pixels in some parts and increases them in others. Because you are using binary threshold, the values will become either black or white.

See the links below, they exactly explain what each of the functions that you are using do and how to use them:

- http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter/gausian_median_blur_bilateral_filter.html
- http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html
- http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html

Comment: One useful thing - while debugging yuor project you may use NativeViewer(http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Debug_in_Visual_Studio_using_NativeViewer) to see current state of images. It's working only on visual studio and support only RGB and GRAY images, but still is very useful and saves a lot of time.